# How to work with continuous flow of data in an app when item is changed for best performance [Xamarin forms]

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am currently working in an app where a lot of continuous info will be flowing around where lists etc will need to be updated in realtime depending on if new items are added or removed.

What i currently did is a solution with messaging center but I am unsure if this is a good practice and if it would effect performance since there will be a lot of users in the app subscribing to this event.

When a user uploads new item to the database:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object, string[]>(this, "AddedData", ObjectID); `
```

Then have this to rest of the users to subscribe to event.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string> (this, "AddedData", async (sender, msg) =>  { 
    //Load new item with objectid 
} } );`
```

Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're expecting the MessagingCenter to somehow send/receive messages from a server of some kind. The MessagingCenter is just used for messages to be sent/received within a single instance of the application running on a single device.

Instances of the application will never receive the messages sent from another device.

Comment: Oh ok. So if a user sends something with the messagecenters then it will only the user that will be able to subscribe? Ok, i would need to change the approach. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to use an external server of some sort. A cloud-based approach would probably be the easiest method. I believe most cloud providers (definitely Microsoft Azure) have some sort of cloud-based message queue which sounds like exactly what you're looking for. A user will post a message from your app, then you'll send that data to the message queue in the cloud where it's stored and can be retrieved by other users of your app.